# Lowest and Highest Block Address in A Cache

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, gem5

I am trying to find the lowest and highest possible block address so that I can generate a random block address. How can I find those addresses? I can only reach to the block addresses that were targeted by the application that is simulated when I use Cache debug flag.

Comment: Upstream thread: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg16753.html